# Unable to send mail to Opportunityowner, Account owner and Creator

Tags: batch

I want to send mail to Opportunity Public group , but I am not understanding where I am making mistake. I am using `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();`.
I have created batch class so when ever the batch is executed the mail should be send but it is not sending.

```
global class oppstage implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext bc){
            return database.getQueryLocator(label.oppStageLabel);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Opportunity> records){
        system.debug(records);
        list<Opportunity> updatedopp = new list<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity obj:records){
            Date Extra10 = obj.CloseDate.addDays(10);
              if(Extra10 == Date.today())
                obj.stagename = 'Closed Won';
                updatedopp.add(obj);
            }
        }
        if(!updatedopp.isEmpty())
        {
            update updatedopp;
        }
    }
    global void finish (Database.BatchableContext BC){
        Opportunity oppDetails = [Select id, StageName, Owner.Email , createdById From Opportunity Where id=: BC.getJobId() ];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        string[] toAddress = new String[]{oppDetails.OwnerId};
            message.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        message.setSubject('Opportuinity Stage' + oppDetails.StageName);
        message.setPlainTextBody('Stage Closed');
        messaging.sendEmail(new messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{Message});
    }
}
```

Comment: your finish query is wrong. BC.getJobId will return the job id of the batch job and not Opportunity Id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your finish Method is querying on `BC.getJobId()` which will return the Job Id of the batch job. It won't give any results on your Opportunity Query.

Secondly, if you want to query on Public Groups then you need first query the `group` and `groupmember` objects. Say for example,

```
    List<String> idList = new List<String>();
        List<String> mailToAddresses = new List<String>(); 
         
        Group gp = [SELECT (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM Group WHERE Name = 'MyPublicGroup'];
        for (GroupMember gm : gp.GroupMembers) {
            idList.add(gm.UserOrGroupId);
        }
//you can add a check if the userorgroupid belongs to user
//String.valueOf(gm.UserOrGroupId).startsWith('005') do this if check and then add it to idList
        List<User> userList = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :idList];
        for(User u : userList) {
            mailToAddresses.add(u.email);
        } 
. . . 
. . . 
message.setToAddresses(mailToAddresses);
```

Check your code on finish() method. If its just that you need to send mail to a public group users / members then Opportunity reference is not required, but if this group is associated with an opportunity then you can get the specify record ids of opportunity and send email to public groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the email address instead of the user ID

```
email.setToAddresses(new String[] {op.Owner.Email});
```